# typescript for web forms

Tags: asp.net, webforms, typescript, asp.net-4.5

Is typescript supported on web forms?

I have an existing asp.net 4.5 web forms project where typescript does not seem to be working.
I cannot create a new file, but even if I rename an existing to .ts it does not seem to be working. No build, no intellisense, nothing!

Comment: Actually, I found that the problem starts from the fact that although for MVC projects the "build action" property of a .ts file is "TypeScriptCompile", this option is not available on web forms projects. I event entered this by hand but it raised an error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found the answers to my problems:

1. I was trying to find "Typescript file" in Web folder of the "Add New Item" dialog, although it is in the "Visual C#" folder ..... Why?
2. Unless you have a .ts file created with "Add New Item" in your project, the option "TypeScriptCompile" on the "Build Action" of the file properties **is not available** and it raises an exception. After the first file is created, then you find this option and can manually set it to a .ts file.
3. The option "Typescript file" is not available in the "Add File" options unless you have a .ts file created with "Add New Item" in your project **and** you are in a "Scripts" folder (if you name differently the folder where you want to add this file, this option wont be available). Of course you can add a .ts file from "Add New Item".
4. You cannot **easily** create a ts file by your own, you **must** use "New Typescript file" from menu. That is because: **A)** *The code page of the file* ***must not be Unicode*** (I was trying to figure out that problem for many hours). if you try to compile a unicode .ts file with tsc, nothing happens!! After I saved the .ts file as Greek(Windows) - in my case-, everything worked fine! **B)** The .csproj properties that must be set for each file to work correctly are quite complex. (I was trying to create a .ts file starting from a .js file and renaming afterwards.... and then playing with .csproj)

Comment: @user1749204 He means make sure the code page is not Unicode [`CP_UNICODE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms715184.aspx).

Comment: @george-mavritsakis - is/was your Web forms a Web Site or Web Application? I'm trying to use Typescript in a Web Site but I don't have a .csproj to add a "build action".

Answer (score 5):

I just created a new Web Application using web forms (empty project).

I found I have to add the Target to my project file...

```
   <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <Exec Command="&quot;$(PROGRAMFILES)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\0.8.0.0\tsc&quot; @(TypeScriptCompile ->'&quot;%(fullpath)&quot;', ' ')" />
  </Target>
```

You need to right-click and select "Unload project", then right-click and select "Edit". This block can go right at the end, just before the `</Project>` tag.

I didn't have any problems adding a TypeScript file in Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: What happens if you manually run tsc on the file: `tsc pathtofile.ts`?

Comment: Nothing happens!!!! Sohnee, I found that it was a code page issue.... Check below. Thanks for your support!

Comment: I think "Install-Package TypeScript.Compile" can do too .