# How to add TypeScript to Visual Studio 2012 ASP.net web forms web-site?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, typescript

I'm trying to add TypeScript to an existing:

- web-site (not a web-application)
- web forms (not MVC)
- Visual Studio 2012

I think, at a fundamental level, the problem is that an ASP.net **web-site** has no project. This means there is no ability to define **"Build options"**. An ASP.net web-site cannot declare that a `*.ts` file should have a build action of **Compile**, since without a project file there are no build actions.

Obviously i'm not going to convert to a web-application (due to the [unresolvable disadvantages of a web-applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547590.aspx)).

Having said that, how do i add TypeScript to an:

- ASP.net
- web-site
- web-forms
- Visual Studio 2012

solution?

## Bonus Reading

- [Using TypeScript in an existing Visual Studio Web Site project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12867390/using-typescript-in-an-existing-visual-studio-web-site-project) (web-application)
- [How do I add typescript to an existing Asp.Net MVC project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12680486/how-do-i-add-typescript-to-an-existing-asp-net-mvc-project) (mvc web-application)
- [typescript for web forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13069825/typescript-for-web-forms) (web-application)
- [Converting existing JavaScript code to TypeScript in Visual Studio](http://igorzelmanovich.blogspot.ca/2013/01/converting-existing-javascript-code-to.html) (web-application)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add typescript files to the project and manage the compilation externally (outside of visual studio) using something like grunt-ts https://github.com/basarat/grunt-ts (disclaimer : I am one of the authors)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a *.ts file to the web folder, then run the ts compiler from the command prompt.

Or create a separate web app with just the TS file.  Then in the build properties, add a command to copy it to the desired location.